# Why my Angular component doesn't reload and show the changes?

Tags: angular

I have a component (show-inspection) that contain a table which gets filled with data from a database. Whenever I add an item to that table I have to refresh the page to see the changes. Why is that ?

Here are the HTML of my components:

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Inspection App</h1>
    <app-show-inspection></app-show-inspection>
</div>
```

### show-inspection-component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#inspectionTypesModal">
    Show Inspection Types
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-end me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" (click)="notEdit()">
    Add Inspection
</button>
  


<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Inspection Type</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of inspectionList">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{inspectionTypesMap.get(item.inspectionTypeId)}}</td>
            <td>{{item.status}}</td>
            <td>{{item.comments}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="add-success-alert">
    Inspection successfully added!
</div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="inspectionTypesModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="inspectionTypesModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="inspectionTypesModalLabel">Inspection Types</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p *ngFor="let type of inspectionTypesList">{{type.id}} - {{type.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <app-add-edit-inspection [inspectionTypesList]="inspectionTypesList" [statusList]="statusList" [isEdit]="isEdit" ></app-add-edit-inspection>
```

### add-edit-inspection.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">{{modalTitle}}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="add-edit-modal-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="inspectionTypeId" class="form-label">Inspection Type</label>
                    <select class="form-select" name="inspectionTypeId" id="inspectionTypeId"
                        [(ngModel)]="inspectionTypeId">
                        <option *ngFor="let type of inspectionTypesList" [value]="type.id">{{type.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="status" class="form-label">Status</label>
                    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="status">
                        <option *ngFor="let status of statusList" value="{{status.statusOption}}">{{status.statusOption}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="comments" class="form-label">Comments</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comments" [(ngModel)]="comments">
                </div>

                <button (click)="addInspection()" *ngIf="isEdit == false" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Add
                </button>
                <button (click)="updateInspection()" *ngIf="isEdit == true" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Update
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the JS of the components

### show-inspection.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InspectionApiService } from 'src/app/services/inspection-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-inspection',
  templateUrl: './show-inspection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-inspection.component.css']
})
export class ShowInspectionComponent implements OnInit {
  inspectionList!: any[];
  inspectionTypesList!: any[];
  statusList!: any[];
  isEdit!: boolean;
  inspectionTypesMap:Map<number,string> = new Map();


  constructor(private service: InspectionApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getInspections().subscribe(inspections => this.inspectionList = inspections);
    this.service.getInspectionTypes().subscribe(inspectionTypes => this.inspectionTypesList = inspectionTypes);
    this.service.getStatuses().subscribe(statuses => this.statusList = statuses);
    this.refreshInspectionTypesMap();
  }


  refreshInspectionTypesMap() {
    this.service.getInspectionTypes().subscribe(data => {
      this.inspectionTypesList = data;

      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.inspectionTypesMap.set(this.inspectionTypesList[i].id, this.inspectionTypesList[i].name);
      }
    })
  }

  notEdit() {
    this.isEdit = false;
  }

  updateInspectionList() {
    this.service.getInspections().subscribe(inspections => this.inspectionList = inspections);
  }

}
```

### add-edit-inspection.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InspectionApiService } from 'src/app/services/inspection-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-inspection',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-inspection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-inspection.component.css']
})
export class AddEditInspectionComponent implements OnInit {
  modalTitle!: string;
  inspectionTypeId!: number;
  comments!: string;
  status!: string;


  @Input() inspectionTypesList!: any[];
  @Input() statusList!: any[];
  @Input() isEdit!: boolean;
  @Output() onAdd = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() updateList = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor(private service: InspectionApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addInspection() {
    var inspection = {
      status : this.status,
      comments: this.comments,
      inspectionTypeId: this.inspectionTypeId
    }

    this.service.addInspection(inspection);
    var closeModalBtn = document.getElementById('add-edit-modal-close');
      if(closeModalBtn) {
        closeModalBtn.click();
      }

      var showAddSuccess = document.getElementById('add-success-alert');
      if(showAddSuccess) {
        showAddSuccess.style.display = "block";
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        if(showAddSuccess) {
          showAddSuccess.style.display = "none"
        }
      }, 4000);
    

      this.onAdd.emit();
      this.updateList.emit();
  }

  updateInspection() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some modification.

1. `InspectionApiService`

   ```
   addInspection() {
    // ...
    // you need to keep the result in some observable like
    const newData = this.data.value() + result;
    this.data.next(newData);
   }
   ```
2. `ShowInspectionComponent` You need to subscribing any observable only once.

Remove this line.

```
refreshInspectionTypesMap() {
  this.service.getInspectionTypes().subscribe(data => {
    this.inspectionTypesList = data;

    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.inspectionTypesMap.set(this.inspectionTypesList[i].id, this.inspectionTypesList[i].name);
  }
})
}
```

And modify this line inside `ngOnInit(): void`

```
this.service.getInspectionTypes().subscribe(inspectionTypes => this.inspectionTypesList = inspectionTypes);
```

By combine with the removed code.

```
this.service.getInspectionTypes().subscribe(data => {
    this.inspectionTypesList = data;

    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.inspectionTypesMap.set(this.inspectionTypesList[i].id, this.inspectionTypesList[i].name);
  }
});
```